# Function "explode" doesn't work in Beeline

Tags: hive

Creating table like this:

```
create table testexplode(name string, childs array<string>, amap map<string, string>)
row format delimited
    fields terminated by '\t'
    collection items terminated by ','
    map keys terminated by ':' 
    lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

Inserting date sets

```
zhangsan    child1,child2,child3,child4 k1:v1,k2:v2
lisi    child5,child6,child7,child8 k3:v3,k4:v4
```

Querying like this:

```
select explode(childs) from testexplode;
```

This query is fine in hive CLI, but in Beeline, it returns error. Why it fails in Beeline?

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.
```